# Efficient way to find duplicates in a set of 4 numbers

Tags: c

I'm currently writing a program where efficiency is rather important.

In this program I sometimes end up with values from up to 4 different sources. I want to check if any of the values I end up with are the same, and if they are the same I also want to know which sources gave me the same numbers.

I can do this fine on my own, so someone doing this for me is not what I'm looking for, I just wonder what an efficient way of doing this would be. Here's two things I've considered, but I'm hoping there's some more efficient and easy way to do this...

idea 1:

```
struct box
{
    char source; // because it won't be above 4
    char value; // because it will be between 2 and 20
};

struct box boxes[4];
int box_count = 0, i;
for(i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    if(hasValue(i))
    {
        boxes[box_count].source = i;
        boxes[box_count++].value = getValue(i);
    }
}

// idk what to do at this point, but here's how to access them...
for(i=0; i<box_count; i++)
{
    printf("source, id : %d, %d\n", boxes[i].source, boxes[i].value);
}
```

idea 2:

```
struct sources
{
    char sources[4]; // because max 4 sources
    char sources_count;
};

struct sources sources[19] = { 0 }; // because only values between 2 and 20
int i, j, v;
for(i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    if(hasValue(i))
    {
        v = getValue(i)-2; // only between 2 and 20, and array of size 19
        sources[v].sources[sources[v].sources_count++] = i;
    }
}

for(i=0; i<19; i++)
{
    if(sources[i].sources_count>0)
    {
        printf("Duplicate sources: %d", sources[i].sources[0]);
        for(j=1; j<sources[i].sources_count; j++)
        {
            printf(", %d", sources[i].sources[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

So is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Improving efficiency belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)  ( as long as your code works )

Comment: Alright, perhaps I should post the question there then. :) Thanks!

Comment: @ArunA.S Well, I posted it there, and they just put it on hold and told me to go here. I really just need help with getting the idea of a more efficient algorithm, not improving an algorithm I've already made.

Comment: I saw your question there. You need to post your real code over there, your real working code which you want to get optimized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 6 compares, say the numbers are, a,b,c,d, then you need to check a==b, a==c, a==d, b==c, b==d, c==d.

If you need to turn this into a state, try this:

```
    s  = (a == b) ?  1 : 0;
    s |= (a == c) ?  2 : 0;
    s |= (a == d) ?  4 : 0;
    s |= (b == c) ?  8 : 0;
    s |= (b == d) ? 16 : 0;
    s |= (c == d) ? 32 : 0;
```

or this

```
    s  = (a ^ b) ? 0 :  1;  
    s |= (a ^ c) ? 0 :  2;  
    s |= (a ^ d) ? 0 :  4;  
    s |= (b ^ c) ? 0 :  8;  
    s |= (b ^ d) ? 0 : 16;  
    s |= (c ^ d) ? 0 : 32;
```

On Microsoft compilers on X86, either sequence is implemented without any branches. Then use switch(s) with 64 cases, 0 through 63. Note that only 15 of the 64 states are valid, the rest are invalid, but setting all those invalid cases to a default failure case will allow the switch case to use a single 64 entry branch target table.

Comment: So you think 6 compares is faster than the second idea? I do tend to agree, just kinda wanted to avoid doing that.

Comment: @HorseSMith - the 6 compares take up more code, but no looping or histogram (counts) table is involved. Since the values are limited to 2 to 20, you could index into a table of 160000 cases with table[(((a*20)+b)*20+c)*20+d], but that's a big table. I think there are 15 cases, 1 no dups, 6 single pairs, 3 double pairs, 4 triplets, 1 quad.

Comment: The outer loop would be max 19 rounds, the inner loop would run max 4 times in total over all of those 19 rounds. I don't know what the compiler would optimize it to, I guess I'll just have to test various methods, but the best could just be 6 checks.

Comment: @HorseSMith - The huge table size should be 19448, table[(((a*21)+b)*21+c)*21+d], to avoid having to subtract from the 4 values. So that's one index calculation (3 multiplies, 3 adds) one table lookup, followed by a switch case statement for the 15 cases, which should use a jump table. Despite the conditional branching, the 6 compares would probably be faster. Do you care if there are two sets of duplicates among the 4 values (3 possible cases), or more than 2 elements with the same value?

Comment: I want all of those that are alike, either it be 2, 3 or 4 alike or 2 pairs. I don't need to separate if 2 pairs.

Comment: @HorseSMith - so you don't care if the case is a==b, c==d (b != c) versus a==b==c==d ?

Comment: Just want to point out that your last edit makes it seem like there are 64 different outcomes, but I only found 14 (excluding 0). That would be 1, 2, 4, 8, 11, 12, 16, 18, 21, 32, 33, 38, 56, 63. For example 3, you can never get it, because to get it you'd need 1|2, but that means a=b and a=c, which means b=c, so that means we got: 1|2|8, which is not 3 but 11. :) Please say so if I've missed a possible value. :s

Comment: @HorseSMith - doing the compares one pair at a time results in 64 cases. Think if it like a table of 64 elements with only 15 possible values. You could index a table of 64 elements to get one the 15 possible values, then use a switch case, or you can use a switch case where all the invalid cases  go to a default failure case, so that the switch case indexes a table of 64 branch targets, of which 15 are valid.